# HTML to PDF convert in react js using jsPDF not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jspdf

after executing the below function getting error
In function, simple HTML div tags are inserted but still not working

exportPDF function will call when one button will click to generate pdf

**Function**

```
const exportPDF = () => {
   let element=(<div style={{display: "flex",flexWrap:"wrap"}}>Sample Text</div>)
   const doc = new jsPDF();
   doc.html(element, {
       callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save('sample.pdf');
         }
     });
}
```

**Error**

```
jspdf.es.min.js:128 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown source type.
    at Promise.<anonymous> (jspdf.es.min.js:128:1)
```

I'm using npm package of jsPDF (***"jspdf": "^2.4.0"***)

Unable to figure out why **doc.html** not working in this code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `reactjs` just convert your element to `html` and then pass it to the `jspdf` like below

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

export default function App() {
  const exportPDF = () => {
    let element = (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>Sample Text</div>
    );
    const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");
    doc.html(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element), {
      callback: function (doc) {
        doc.save('sample.pdf');
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={exportPDF}>export</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing jsx in my opinion because it is react js.

if you try in a simple project with HTML js and not react js I think you will get result.

for doing this I have a case like you several months ago. finally I did that with node js and not react js. node js and  pure html css.

Comment: I want to make it in react js only. how do achieve it? OR else you are said that it's possible in node js then how I can do it in node js with react? please give me solution